# wamp server 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote this code for my `.htaccess`

```
RewirteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f

RewriteRule^(.*)$index.php?url=$1[L,QSA]
```

when I wrote this code my wamp server gave me an error 500 internal server error

when i checked my apache error log it gave this error message:

```
C:/wamp64/www/testapp/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d' C:/wamp64/www/testapp/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d'
```

what seem to be the issue here please. Responses needed

Comment: there's no php/mysql here, just `.htaccess` directives.

Comment: Spaces are used as delimiters in Apache config files. You are missing a lot of spaces/delimiters so the arguments are merging into one, which is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues and typos in your `.htaccess` snippet.

Here is a corrected version

```
# was: RewirteEngine on
RewriteEngine on

# was: one line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# was: no spaces
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```